# How to generate Spring SOAP Web Service base URL to display list of Web Service methods

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws

Publish Spring Web Service with base URL which displays the list of Web Service methods in the same way as .NET Web Services .asmx file does

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx

I want the same base URL type to display list of operations using spring soap webservice.

Comment: I have created a Spring SOAP Web Service With one Endpoint Class having two operations. I can access the wsdl for the operations. What I exactly need is to have a base / root URL which can display the name of the Web Service Operations.  For your reference please access this URL as an example.  
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. And while you are at it, make your title smaller and more readable.

Comment: I want the same functionality to be in Spring Web Service to display the same way the list of Web Service operations as .NET asmx file is displaying. The reason why we are looking for such a case is that our client has asked us to provide a base URL with the list of Operations listed.